# Binding route name in repeater item template

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Sorry for bad question statement..

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rp_Route" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_Route" runat="server" PostBackUrl="<%$RouteUrl:routename=RouteHome%>">'<%# Eval("text") %>'</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Repeater Binding

```
rp_Route.DataSource = _route.Get(route_id)
rp_Route.DataBind();
```

How can i bind route name, as in my code i have hard code **RouteHome** but i want to set route name according to my sql table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetRouteUrl` to retrieve URL by route name:

```
PostBackUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl( Eval("RouteName").ToString(), null )%>'
```

Note that we are passing null for parameters as you do appear to have any, and `RouteName` is just my guess at the column name that contains routes